# How to integrate Xenomai 3 with Nvidia cuda?

Tags: nvidia, cuda, realtime

I use Ubuntu 16.04.2 64bits.

I heard that Xenomai 2.x/3.x could not support Nvidia CUDA drivers.

Is that true?

If yes, how to solve it?

Is there exist any software that can allocate one CPU dedicate only for Xenomai Linux thread, and others CPUs for Xenomai RT threads?

Is that possible?

Comment: *Beware that a 4.x series kernel won't work with many of the hardware accelerated functions, e.g., you won't be able to use the GPU for accelerated graphics or CUDA.* Commented here: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/948075/installing-xenomai/

Comment: Is this page solve the issue you mentioned? https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1004330/4-10-kernel-ubuntu-16-04-17-04-support/